# Export FBX : Material Blend and Shadow mode won't remain as 'Alpha Clip'

Tags: materials, export, transparency, .fbx, blend-modes

I'm trying to export my project as an FBX.

However, when I export and then import the file, the "Blend Mode" and "Shadow Mode" option for the material is set to 'Opaque'.

I want this material in the exported FBX to be set to 'Alpha Clip' mode, but it won't remain as such.

Any comment would be helpful!
[image]

Comment: [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: thanks @JohnEason i already applied UV coordinates , but the problem is still there cuz i have to set blend-modes of UV coodrdinates to 'Alpha Clip'